# How to get left Taskbar like thing from Ubuntu in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, taskbar

Sorry for not knowing the technical term for the taskbar in Ubuntu. Can I get that thing also in Lubuntu?

I'm talking about this thing below

[image]

Comment: No you can't. Sorry to say :'-(

Answer (score 1):

It's called `Dash` ans is part of Unity(with Gnome 3). So if you try to bring it is Lubuntu, then it's goodbye LXDE.

Rather, it would be best to install Ubuntu, or install unity side-by-side with LXDE.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install an application like `Docky` which is kinda like it. (more like the dock in Mac OS X actually). It's not as feature rich but it can at least be used as a convenient place for often used apps!